# heroku deploy issue says ktor env

Tags: kotlin, heroku, intellij-idea, ktor

i got the same problem every time i try to deploy to heruko

https://prnt.sc/IeH3wooTqqAj

a screenshot from the terminal
1- https://prnt.sc/fqpj3f2lQTz8
2- https://prnt.sc/-710l_bznc2B

this is my application.kt

```
    fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8087, host = "0.0.0.0") {
    module {
    module()
    }
     }.start(wait = true)
     }

     Suppress("unused")
     fun Application.module() {
     configureKoin()
     configureAuth()
     configureRouting()
     configureSerialization()
     configureMonitoring()
     configureSession()
      }
```

Prockfile

web: build/install/com.example.googleauth/bin/com.example.googleauth
worker: python scheduler.py

every thing is uptodate and i also add the Config Vars on heroku setting
i also tryed the embedded way and also the engin way same issue

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace of an error? I can't see an actual error on the screenshot.

Comment: here is the screenshot 
1- https://prnt.sc/fqpj3f2lQTz8
2-https://prnt.sc/-710l_bznc2B

Comment: What version of Ktor do you use?

Comment: 2.0.3 , everything is updated

Comment: Could you please try to disable the development mode https://ktor.io/docs/development-mode.html#application-conf? Also, do you have this problem when running your server locally?

Comment: i tryed it with dev mode on and off same error message aslo i run the code on lochal host its work really fine , i don't know if its help but im also using mongodb and i added the database name env in both intellij and heroku

Comment: I suggest removing modules one by one before deploying to Heroku to locate where the actual problem is.